# When I run composer update I get a fatal error

Tags: laravel

When I run `composer update` I get the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Symfony\Component\Console\Formatter\WrappableOutputFormatterInterface' not found in /var/www/html/danceGitHub/dance/vendor/symfony/console/Formatter/OutputFormatter.php on line 22

Comment: remove the vendor folder and try `composer install`

Comment: thanks it's good but i dont know where this errors comes .